# Hiding the tabs appearance of intellij idea 2018

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I am trying to hide the tabs screen (which i placed on the left, see screenshot 2), just as other screen parts kan be hidden. I am using intellij idea 2018. I have the tabs appearance set to the left, see screenshot 2. I can't find any options to automatically hide this left screen, just as is possible with the projects view (screenshot 3).

Any idea's?

1) My main development view
[image: My main development view]

[2) The tabs options
[image: The tabs options]

3) Projects view
[image: Projects view]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set placement to "none" if you want to hide it completely. I don't think there is a way to temporarily hide them.

[image: Hide editor tabs]

Comment: Very nice solution, found a way to assign shortcuts to those actions. Now the pane can be hidden in a fast way:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TYV4.png